# How to skip alphabet strings and accept float/integer

Tags: ruby

I have a set of string. I want to skip those which have all characters and consider only string which have characters in [0-9] or "." i.e. float.

How can I do this. I tried using `if str[/[a-zA-Z]+/]  == str`. But this gives me error in case of integers/float

```
if str[/[a-zA-Z]+/]  == str
    continue
else
    //do something
```

This gives error: `can't convert Regexp into Integer`
Thanks

Comment: Give the string and output you are expecting ?

Comment: If string is all characters e.g. "abcd" then `continue`, else `do something`

Comment: `if str[/[a-zA-Z]+/]  == str` it shouldn't give error.. Something wrong some where else

Comment: Could you give the full error stack ? I am interested first why the error, then possible solution...

Comment: What is `str`? An array or a string?

Comment: Are you really sure? I'd double check since `Array.new[/foo/] # => TypeError: can't convert Regexp into Integer` while `String.new[/foo/] # => nil`.

Comment: @nish If `str` is a string, 100% sure.. I am..the error shouldn't come. Just try to confirm `str.to_s[/[a-zA-Z]+/]  == str.to_s`

Comment: @toro2k You missed one,. I did `123[/\d+/]`.. will give you the same error..

Comment: One more way to debug just put `puts str.class` before the line `if str[/[a-zA-Z]+/]  == str`. Tell me the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering OP is looking for non numeric string to continue:-- and str is a String class object, for e.g. str = "abcd" or str = "1.95" etc.

```
regExp = /^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/

unless str[regExp].eql?(str)
    # continue
else 
    # do something
end
```

Comment: why err - *can't convert Regexp into Integer*? Any explanation ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Now I have added few valid examples for str variable, which should avoid error mentioned. Here OP might be using say str = 1.96 then doing reg match, hence error might have happened.

Comment: Yes.. That is the reason.. I was expecting you to write your answer.. I knew, but waiting to post it  till OP confirming.

Comment: @nish You should.. Because this answer didn't fix actual problem you are having. Give us those information, I asked in the comment.

Comment: @nish what is str value, you may provide your error stack or just str you use. if you are assigning number(whole or float) it should be string numeric.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (str =~ /[a-zA-Z]+/).nil? #if there are no letters in str
  #continue with string
else
  #Regex test failed
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you please provide some commentary as to what it is doing? If posting another answer, can you also make sure it improves on answers that have already been posted.